# no breakpoints can be set VS2010?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, compilation, breakpoints

This is happening to me very often. When I am working in Visual Studio 2010 and say I make a code change, then build... Both my existing breakpoints become disabled / and or cannot be set and I also cannot set new breakpoints. Does anyone have a solution for this? It is very annoying. So far the only way I have been able to get around this is to restart Visual Studio which can take 5 to 8 minutes to reindex everything or to try rebuilding individual projects in my solution. My solution consists of several DLLs which make up the entire program.

Comment: What kind of projects are you working on?

Comment: I'm working on an enterprise system which contains several major projects or sub-applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the post.build file contained numerous conditions for whether or not it should copy several DLLs to a target directory... Since I didn't have time to pick through the xml for these actions I just used a bash script to copy the files after building. No need to get complicated... Otherwise, the formal solution involves setting conditions for allowing the DLLs to be overwritten/copied after compile or not.

I find the Visual Studio post.build file concept a little excessive since in the end it will make little difference whether a dll is overwritten with a freshly compiled version, yet, if you make code changes, compile, and it doesn't copy to the target directory you end up running your app with an out of date DLL and you are not testing with the recent code change..! Others have even implemented the post.build file complete with xml and goto statements...! Leave it to Microsoft to complicate the build & debug process...

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the dependencies set correctly in your projects. I know my breakpoints will become disabled if the code is "out of date". If you don't have the dependencies set up right, then when the updated code is rebuilt it will not rebuild all of the related code which will then leave those modules "out of date".

Since this is VS 2010, the dependencies are on the project not on the solution (you can add solution dependencies, but project dependencies will carry over into a new solution so it is the better way to go when possible).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused when you having your Configuration Manager settings set to Release rather than Debug.

In Visual Studios select Build from the menu, then Configuration Manager.

In the next dialog select your project, then locate the drop down menu near the top left corner titled "Active solution configuration:" Make sure it is set to Debug.

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if your code is under version control start afresh by checking out the head revision, do another clean and rebuild and start debugging again.

This for whatever reason enabled me to insert breakpoints in my VS 2010 C# project once again, whereas no amount of fannying around with properties, configurations etc got rid of my phantom breakpoint problem.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I found for this was to quit my Windows job and get another job as a Mac Developer where we use Xcode.! What a huge difference.! I sure haven't seen that breakpoints problem again.!